# What kind of weatherproof(?) RJ45 connector is this?

Tags: networking, cable

We bought a IP based intercom and the outdoor unit has a ethernet socket that looks like this:

[image]

I did find a fitting plug/cover [here](http://www.fleconn-china.com/productinfo-481-IP66-IP67-Male-to-Female-Outdoor-Waterproof-RJ45-Ethernet-Extension-Cable.html) but does this thing have any specific name?

Answer (score 1):

Copied from that website:

MALE TO FEMALE OUTDOOR WATERPROOF RJ45 ETHERNET EXTENSION CABLE

It is a type of cable, so it does not have a name of its own.